# Repeating div with form fields

Tags: jquery, repeat

I have a form where I want to be able to duplicate a group of fields as many times as I want.  And I also want to have field `id`, `name`, and label's `for` attributes of those new group of fields increase by 1. I've tried this so far with jQuery, and got it to at least duplicate the group of fields, but remove doesn't work.  And I'm not sure how to do +1 for each of those 3 attributes.  I appreciate any help I can get.

Here's a jsfiddle of it,
http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="inlineForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="repeatingSection">
        <a href="#" class="buttonGray buttonRight deleteFight">Delete</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="fighter_a_id_1" id="fighter_a_id_1" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fighter_b_id_1" id="fighter_b_id_1" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="winner_id_1" id="winner_id_1" value="" />
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="fighter_a_1">Fighters</label>
            <input type="text" name="fighter_a_1" id="fighter_a_1" value="" /> <span class="formTextExtraCenter">vs</span> <input type="text" name="fighter_b_1" id="fighter_b_1" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="fighter_a_pay_1">Fighter Pay $</label>
            <input type="text" name="fighter_a_pay_1" id="fighter_a_pay_1" value="" /> <span class="formTextExtraCenter">vs</span> <input type="text" name="fighter_b_pay_1" id="fighter_b_pay_1" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="winner_1">Winner</label>
            <input type="text" name="winner_1" id="winner_1" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="method_1">Method</label>
            <input type="text" name="method_1" id="method_1" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="method_type_1">Method Type</label>
            <input type="text" name="method_type_1" id="method_type_1" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="round_1">Round</label>
            <input type="text" name="round_1" id="round_1" class="fieldSmall" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="time_1">Time</label>
            <input type="text" name="time_1" id="time_1" class="fieldSmall" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="formRow">
            <label for="fight_number_1">Fight #</label>
            <input type="text" name="fight_number_1" id="fight_number_1" class="fieldSmall" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formRowRepeatingSection">
            <a href="#" class="buttonGray buttonRight addFight">Add Fight</a>
        </div>
    <div class="formRow">
        <input type="submit" class="submitButton" value="Save Fights" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
// Add a new repeating section
$('.addFight').click(function(){
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
    lastRepeatingGroup.clone().insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
    return false;
});
// Delete a repeating section
$('.deleteFight').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should automatically rename according all three elements:

```
// Add a new repeating section
$('.addFight').click(function(){
    var currentCount =  $('.repeatingSection').length;
    var newCount = currentCount+1;
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
    var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone();
    newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
    newSection.find("input").each(function (index, input) {
        input.id = input.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
        input.name = input.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    });
    newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
        var l = $(label);
        l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
    });
    return false;
});

// Delete a repeating section
$('.deleteFight').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    return false;
});​
```

I changed the delete handler, to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead, so that the handler would also be attached to newly created copies of that button. Now, if you're using jquery > 1.7 you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The on() version would be:

```
// Delete a repeating section
$(document).on('click','.deleteFight',function(){
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Cool exactly what I needed.  I was trying to get it to work with .on since I do use the latest jQuery, but you responded before I figured it out.  Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: No prob ;-) Yeah, I figured I'd rather just add it and not leave it with deprecated code.

Comment: I know this is an old one but got a question.  If someone added say 4 more so current count is now 5.  Then they deleted say the third one. You would now have 1,2,4,5 and if they clicked on add flight there would there now be two listed as 5 for each field or I am not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Wow, haven't seen this code in 9 years, but actually, i think you are right! :D If I remember correctly my solution was based on something I had done in the past where deletions of elements were not proper removals of the elements, but rather mark a property as "Deleted" internally and then hide the row. Since I needed a backend to take action, or something like that on form submission. If elements are going to be removed like that then you probably want to rename elements in the entire section with a new incremental sequence, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use this after you clone your object

Fiddle around :) http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/MZjKR/1/

I'll leave some TODO for you, change the 3 to the current number of id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.id_changer = function(new_id) {
  return this.each(function(){
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        var ob = $(this);
        ob.attr('id',   this.id.replace(/_\d$/, '_' + new_id));
        ob.attr('name', this.name.replace(/_\d$/, '_' + new_id));           
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Tip: Write re-usable codes so if ever you encounter same situation in the future you can "re-use" the codes.
Also, as jQuery's motto, write less code and do more!

Comment: The delete function in this fiddle does not work. :-(
Please be careful to add only functioning solutions.

Comment: use `$('form').on('click', '.deleteFight', function(){` to fix delete problem

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version.

http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/27/

It relies heavily on the index of the repeating region. So don't add any siblings above it. If you do need that, then wrap all repeating regions in another div.

Damn! too late :) anyway... here's the code.

```
// Add a new repeating section
var attrs = ['for', 'id', 'name'];
function resetAttributeNames(section) { 
    var tags = section.find('input, label'), idx = section.index();
    tags.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $.each(attrs, function(i, attr) {
        var attr_val = $this.attr(attr);
        if (attr_val) {
            $this.attr(attr, attr_val.replace(/_\d+$/, '_'+(idx + 1)))
        }
      })
    })
}

$('.addFight').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
        var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true)  
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
        resetAttributeNames(cloned)
    });

// Delete a repeating section
$('.deleteFight').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var current_fight = $(this).parent('div');
        var other_fights = current_fight.siblings('.repeatingSection');
        if (other_fights.length === 0) {
            alert("You should atleast have one fight");
            return;
        }
        current_fight.slideUp('slow', function() {
            current_fight.remove();

            // reset fight indexes
            other_fights.each(function() {
               resetAttributeNames($(this)); 
            })            
        })   
    });


​
```

Comment: I like the solution, Can you  also help about, how to save submitted values from all repeating section to a test file on submit button click ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `name=method[]` etc etc as your fields, you'll get arrays in the POST variable so you don't need explicit indexing.