# Showing a hidden div within a cloned div

Tags: jquery, hide, clone

I'm trying to make a form where a dropdown menu can be repeated several times, and which can trigger the display of a form supplement that follows it.

I've got the duplication down thanks to this example: [Repeating div with form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380045/repeating-div-with-form-fields), but the duplicated menus aren't triggering the display of the hidden section of the form. I don't have much experience with jquery, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's a jsfiddle, and the code:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jP8cW/2/

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="repeatingSection">
        <select id="j_id_1" name="j_id_1">
            <option value="none">SELECT TITLE</option>
            <option value="new">New title</option>
            <option value="other">Other titles</option>
        </select>
        <div class="hidden">
            <h3>New Journal Info</h3>
            <p>
                <label for="title">Title: </label>
                <input type="text" name="j_title" id="title"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="addJourn">Add Journal</a>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.addJourn').click(function(){
    var currentCount =  $('.repeatingSection').length;
    var newCount = currentCount+1;
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
    var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone();
    newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
    newSection.find("select").each(function (index, select) {
        select.id = select.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
        select.name = select.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
    });
    newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
        var l = $(label);
        l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
    });
    return false;
});

$("select[id^='j_id']").change(function(){
    var selection = this.value; //grab the value selected
    if (selection==="new"){
        $(this).next('.hidden').show()
    } else {
        $(this).next('.hidden').hide()
    }
});
```

CSS is just `.hidden {display: none;}`

Any advice or insight is very appreciated.

Comment: That looks like WAYYY more code than you need... thought about using `index` ??

Comment: just out of curiosity, why you duplicate the `select`? Isn't one enough?

Comment: you're also cloning elements with ID which will result in **duplicate ID elements** all over the place which will lead you to problems.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was trying to basically auto-increment the IDs, which has been working for the selects but I missed the duplicate IDs in the hidden part of the form. The select is duplicated because it's part of an internal purchase tracking application, so I want people to be able to say "We bought this package of subscriptions, with all of these titles," entering both into the database, as purchases and titles are separate tables with a M:N relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVK5P/2/)

What you are experiencing is the result of incorrect event registration.

At the time that you are registering the 'onchange' event, the new elements do not exist yet.

You need to register the event to each element when you create it.
Or use jQuery 'live' method instead of 'change'.

[.live() docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

In the example below, I am using Javascript and NOT jQuery because the live method did not work correctly with the JSFiddle.

Full solution:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="repeatingSection">
        <select id="j_id_1" name="j_id_1">
            <option value="none">SELECT TITLE</option>
            <option value="new">New title</option>
            <option value="other">Other titles</option>
        </select>
        <div class="hidden">
            <h3>New Journal Info</h3>
            <p>
                <label for="title">Title: </label>
                <input type="text" name="j_title" id="title"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="addJourn">Add Journal</a>
    <p><input type="submit"/></p>
</form>

<style>.hidden {
    display: none;
    }
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.addJourn').click(function(){
    var currentCount =  $('.repeatingSection').length;
    var newCount = currentCount+1;
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
    var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone();
    newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
    newSection.find("select").each(function (index, select) {
        select.id = select.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
        select.name = select.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
        //register the onchange event to the new element
        select.onchange = function(event) {onChange(event)};
    });
    newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
        var l = $(label);
        l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
    });
    newSection.find('.hidden').css('display','none');
    return false;
    });

    //register the onchange event only for the 1st element
    $('#j_id_1').change(function(event) {
        onChange(event);
    });

    //technically, you can use the live() method to register events to elements that do not yet exist. However, it was making problems with the JSFiddle so I skipped it. You may be able to use it in your code though.
});

function onChange(event) {
    var selection = event.target.value;//grab the value selected
    if (selection==="new"){
        $('#' + event.target.id).next('.hidden').show(500);
    } else {
        $('#' + event.target.id).next('.hidden').hide(500);
    }
}

</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I thought that something like that might have been happening, I just didn't have the words to describe it.