# How to duplicate a block of form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, duplicates, increment

I am very new to jQuery, so please bear with me!

I need to duplilicate a chunk of a form where the user can create multiple/indefinite job roles.  I found an approxination of what I was looking for here: [Repeating div with form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380045/repeating-div-with-form-fields), but it doesn't quite finish the job.

What was wrong:
It didn't add a new number to each form field of the new blocks to make them complete.

What I still need:
To add a new heading to the top of each block with an increment of 1 each time (Job 2, Job 3, etc)
Form fields whos IDs and "for"s increment by one each time (primaryJobRole2, primaryJobRole etc)

I managed to get the increasing numbers on to the elements, but the issue is the first time it will be primaryJobRole2, then next time it will be primaryJobRole23 etc.

I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, but I have developed tunnel vision!  Thanks in advance.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="repeat-role">
  <h3>Current Role</h3>

  <label for="primaryJobRole">Job Role:</label>  
  <input id="primaryJobRole" name="primaryJobRole" type="text">

  <label for="currentOrganisation">Current Organisation Name:</label>  
  <input id="currentOrganisation" name="currentOrganisation" type="text"> 

  <label for="currentTitle">Current Title:</label>  
  <input id="currentTitle" name="currentTitle" type="text">

</div>
```

jQuery is:

```
$('.add-role').click(function(){
    var currentCount =  $('.repeat-role').length;
    var newCount = currentCount + 1;
    var newHeading = $('.repeat-role h3').append(' ' + newCount);
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeat-role').last();
    var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone();

    lastRepeatingGroup.removeClass('current-role');
    newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup).hide().addClass('current-role new-role').slideDown(1000);
// this is what I did that adds a number each time instead of incrementing
    newSection.find("input").each(function (index, input) {
        var i = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).attr('id', i + newCount);
    });
// this is what was with the original script which doesn't seem to work at all
    newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
        var l = $('label');
        l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
    });
    return false;
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vmail/hdw4gyyv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify the last section, I edited your logic to use the original section as a template for each new section.  This way you only need to append the new count instead of trying to replace them.

```
$('.add-role').click(function () {
    var currentCount = $('.repeat-role').length;
    var newCount = currentCount + 1;
    var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeat-role').last();
    var template = $('.repeat-role').first();
    var newSection = template.clone();
    var newHeading = $('h3', newSection).append(' ' + newCount);

    lastRepeatingGroup.removeClass('current-role');
    newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup).hide().addClass('current-role new-role').slideDown(1000);
    newSection.find("input").each(function (index, input) {
        var i = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).attr('id', i + newCount);
    });
    newSection.find("label").each(function (index, label) {
        var l = $(this);
        l.attr('for', l.attr('for') + newCount);
    });
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdw4gyyv/1/

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the answer and fiddle to use .on() instead of .click().  Only the first line is affected:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-role', function () {
  ...
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sb8fyehv/

Comment: Perfect - thank you!  I knew it was cloning the last version of itself, but didn't know how to only replicate the initial block of code - thanks again!

Comment: When I click the second add role to add another role it deletes all roles.