# Create repeating form section, remove field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, repeat

I have a form with a repeating section. To create the repeating section, I am using a slight variant of this code:

```
// Add a new repeating section
var attrs = ['for', 'id', 'name'];
function resetAttributeNames(section) { 
    var tags = section.find('input, label'), idx = section.index();
    tags.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $.each(attrs, function(i, attr) {
        var attr_val = $this.attr(attr);
        if (attr_val) {
            $this.attr(attr, attr_val.replace(/_\d+$/, '_'+(idx + 1)))
        }
      })
    })
}

$('.addFight').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
        var cloned = lastRepeatingGroup.clone(true)  
        cloned.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
        resetAttributeNames(cloned)
    });

// Delete a repeating section
$('.deleteFight').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var current_fight = $(this).parent('div');
        var other_fights = current_fight.siblings('.repeatingSection');
        if (other_fights.length === 0) {
            alert("You should atleast have one fight");
            return;
        }
        current_fight.slideUp('slow', function() {
            current_fight.remove();

            // reset fight indexes
            other_fights.each(function() {
               resetAttributeNames($(this)); 
            })            
        })   
    });
```

JSFiddle of it - http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/27/

I originally found the code from this thread:
[Repeating div with form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380045/repeating-div-with-form-fields)

However, there is a problem with this code: if you fill in the form fields, and then click "add fight," the new repeated section not only duplicates the form fields, but also their values.  I think I need to use something like this to clear the values of the new form section:

```
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
```

but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the functions I already have. So how can I clear the value of the fields once the new form section has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all values from all input fields in your newly cloned:

```
cloned.find("input").val("");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/206/)

EDIT:

To reset the radio group you can set their checked value to false:

```
cloned.find("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Unfxn/207/)

Comment: I knew it would be something simple.  Thank you!

Comment: Okay, bonus question... I was hoping I could figure this part out, but no luck yet.  I also want to clear the values of radio buttons and a dropdown select.  How would I do that?

Comment: cloned.find("select").val("");  works for the select, still haven't figured out the radio buttons....

Comment: You need to set their checked value to false. Edited the answer.